# Is it valid to say that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$ holds for all $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it valid to say that:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$$
for all values of x irrespective of whether the taylor series converges for all x? In other words, if we were to sum up all the infinite terms of the taylor series all at once, should we end up with f(x), irrespective of whether the series converges for that particular value of x?

Comment: No, the symbol salad you've written there is not valid in any commonly understood notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n $$
This makes no sense at all unless $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $a$.  It is true (as a convergent series) when $f$ is analytic in 
a disk (in the complex plane) around $a$ with radius greater than $|x-a|$. By Abel's theorem, it is also true when $|x-a|$ is equal to the radius of convergence and the series converges at $x$ and $f$ is continuous on the line segment 
$[a,x]$.
 When that series diverges at $x$ but $f(x)$ exists, various summability methods may or may not produce $f(x)$.  If $f$ is not analytic, all sorts of strange things can happen.

Comment: Yes that should be it. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you should give the canonical example of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function that's not analytic.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD that's $\exp(-x^{-2})$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ in the origin, right?

Comment: That's one of them.